# Magento - Get store id before product create observer

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a few websites to a product based on the current store id in the `catalog_product_save_before` observer.

The observer is working fine, but I can not seem to get the current store id from which the product is created. This is what I tried:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

which returns 0.

Magento treats admin panel as a separate store with name `admin` and id 0. So, it returns the store id for admin, which is not what I want.

So, I tried a few things in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/how-to-get-current-store-id-from-current-scope-in-admin), and it still returns the id as 0.

**More Details:**

I have logged in as a store admin to enterprise.lmm.dev(virtual host for enterprise website) and am creating a product. Here, both the website name and store name is 'enterprise'.

When creating a product, I choose 'enterprise' from the 'Choose Store View' drop-down and fills the product create form.

I have written an observer function 'before_product_save()', in which this is what I do:

```
echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

But, this is returning 0.

I want to know if this is the way to go and if I can access the store id for the store 'enterprise'.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I did not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate it a bit? Especially what you mean with "current store id from which the product is created"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Comment: This returns 0 as well.

Comment: What do you get for Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() ?

Comment: he must be accessing the code in admin, so above will not work unless store id is posted/get

Comment: change store from admin and try to get store id after that.

Comment: getName() returns 'admin'.

Comment: @techguy4web, what do you mean change store from admin?

Comment: @AlbinGeorge, you can't get storeId unless you are in a store scope in admin as techguy4web said

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Yes, I am accessing the code from admin.

Comment: @AlbinGeorge, I mean when you are in Catalog grid section, see a drop down on top of the grid, use that drop-down to change the store

Comment: @techguy4web I tried selecting the store from the drop-down and still, no change. And when I try printing the product data, I am getting the store id of that product as 0.

Comment: are you sure that you are selecting single store rather then all stores during product add/edit?

Comment: @techguy4web yes, I am selecting a single store named 'enterprise' in the 'Choose Store View' drop-down.

Answer (score 3):

At this point `store_id` in the product object has been set to the ID of the store for which you save the current values.

So assuming, `$product` is your product object, you can use this:

```
$product->getStoreId()
```

Or if you need the store model:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($product->getStoreId());
```

Comment: I have already tried this. This also gives the same value - 0.

Comment: When I print `$product->getData()`, in there, it shows the store_id as 0, but the website id is 4. The problem is there are multiple stores within the current website, so I cant pin down the current store from the current website.

Comment: The difference between website_ids and store_id here is: website_ids is an actual product attribute that specifies to which websites the product belongs. There is no such thing for stores, a store_id different than 0 just means "save the values for this store id", i.e. you have selected the store from the scope switcher in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

If `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()` not working then try `$this->helper('core')->getStoreId()` or `Mage::helper('core')->getStoreId()`

Comment: Paste your code here so I can check the exact issue

Comment: This is my code in the observer function: `echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); die();`, and this prints 0.